# How to solve a coupled, first-order, non-linear equation with first derivatives of multiple functions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I am interested in solving a differential equation of the form

$$\left(\frac{dx}{dr}\right)^{\!2}=F(x,y)+G(x)\left(\frac{dy}{dr}\right)^{\!2}$$

The reason most of my tricks don't work are that $F$ and $G$ are relatively complicated, and I'm not sure how to deal with the two nonlinear derivatives.

I do know that there are numerical methods that might work, for instance, I could take a derivative, set $a=dx/dr$, $b=dy/dr$ and form a linear system, but I'd like to check analytic approaches first.

EDIT: Following recommendations from comments, I'll post the precise forms of $F$ and $G$ - hope it doesn't make people ignore my question!

\begin{align*}
F(x,y)&=\frac{1-b^2}{|\wp(z,\omega_1,\omega_2)|^2}(1+\cos(x))^2 \\
G(x)&=-\sin^2(x),
\end{align*}

where $b$ is a constant and $\wp(z,\omega_1,\omega_2)$ is the Weierstrass function with periods $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$, with complex domain being mapped to the real domain via
$$z=\tan(x/2)\exp(iy).$$

Comment: If you know the form of $F$ and $G,$ it would be helpful to post that.

Comment: If you have one equation for two functions, there will probably be very many solutions.

Comment: @AdrianKeister: If thought it could help, I would - but F includes Weierstrass functions which are related to the $(x,y)$ through a coordinate transformation, so my feeling is that it will overly complicated the issue.

Comment: @Kusma: Yeah, I guess I'm aware this system is underdetermined, but I haven't ever dealt with something quite like it, so I wasn't really sure. Are you saying this is a waste of time without other restrictions on $x,y$?

Comment: @levitopher: I'd still recommend posting them, and here's why: 1. There may be a user on M.SE who knows what to do with your $F$ and $G$ in context. 2. It's hard to over-contexualize questions on M.SE (we tend to always want MORE and MORE context - though conciseness is not bad, either). 3. If a user wants to do some numerical computations, it will be impossible without knowing $F$ and $G$.

Comment: @AdrianKeister: Ok, done.